# Service will not start: error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: java, windows-services

We have a custom service that we install with our application.  The only problem is that after it is installed, it will not start, generating the error above.  I have tried to diagnose what the problem is, but can't seem to find any useful information as to why it is quitting.  I have tried the same service on a non "R2" 2008 server, and manual it worked fine.

service simple java file running using batch file. Deamon service.

Has anyone had any experience troubleshooting this type of problem, where there are so few clues?

Comment: Goto Registry->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->System->CurrentControlSet->Services. search for the service name you have installed and check the "Start" Value. Or better post all the values found under your Service Name.

Comment: @Abhineet but same setting will run on another system properly.

Comment: Can you post some of your codes? It would be easy to spot the doubt. Late reply k liye sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Goto:

> Registry-> HKEY_LOCAL‌​_MACHINE-> System-> Cur‌​rentControlSet-> Servi‌​ces.

Find the concerned service & delete it. Close regedit. Reboot the PC & Re-install the concerned service. Now the error should be gone.

Comment: For some reason i just cant boot up , it starts windows and doesnt get me to a desktop but reboots again , i just upgraded to vista using xp so i dont know how do i fix it

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem related permission.
Make sure that the current user has access to the folder which contains installation files.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the problem.This is for EAServer Windows Service

Resolution is --> 
Open Regedit in Run prompt

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\EAServer

In parameters, **give SERVERNAME entry as EAServer.**

[It is sometime overwritten with Envirnoment variable : Path value]

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears if the Windows service launcher has quit immediately after being started.
This problem usually happens because the license key has not been correctly deployed(license.txt file in the license folder). 
If service is not strtign with correct key, just put incorrect key and try to start. Once started, place the correct key, it will work.

Comment: I upgraded windows vista from xp , now it just starts , shows me a blue screen . I used Windows Vista iso to get into command prompt of C drive , how do i change the licence.txt

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, I looked into a log file C:\...\mysql\data\VM-IIS-Server.err and found this

```
2016-06-07 17:56:07 160c  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2016-06-07 17:56:07 3392 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-06-07 17:56:07 3392 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-06-07 17:56:07 3392 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-06-07 17:56:07 3392 [ERROR] Aborting
```

The first line says "unable to create temporary file", it sounds like "insufficient privileges", first I tried to give access to mysql folder for my current user - no effect, then after some wandering around I came up to control panel->Administration->Services->Right Clicked MysqlService->Properties->Log On, switched to "This account", entered my username/password, clicked OK, and it woked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error 1067 was caused with a specific version of Tomcat 7.0.96 32-bit in combination with AdoptOpenJDK.  Spent two hours on it, un-installing, re-installing and trying different Java settings but Tomcat would not start. See...
[ASF Bugzilla – Bug 63625](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63625)
seems to point at the issue though they refer to seeing a different error.

I tried 7.0.99 32-bit and it started straight away with the same AdoptOpenJDK 32-bit binary install.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using `Monitor Tomcat` application. I ran it and after a few seconds its icon appeared in my system tray. I right clicked on the icon and clicked the start button and after a few seconds Apache Tomcat started.